# App version always 0.0(0) after upload to fabric beta

Tags: android, continuous-integration, google-fabric, fabric-beta

I have strange problem with app version in fabric beta. After executing task :app:crashlyticsUploadDistribution build uploaded successfully. Version name and version code are correct for build, but version in the list of uploaded builds is always 0.0(0).And after downloading, versions of this builds are correcting. Wrong versions displayed only on fabric. [image: Fabric]

Update:

For setting version name and code I'm using "com.gladed.androidgitversion" plugin  :

```
androidGitVersion {
   format '%tag%'
   }
android {
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my_package"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true

    versionName androidGitVersion.name()
    versionCode androidGitVersion.code()
}

}
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. How and when are you setting your build and version codes?

Comment: @MikeBonnell I use  "com.gladed.androidgitversion" plugin. See update

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, but my hunch is that the name and code are being set after the Fabric Gradle plugin has run and we're not collecting the information.

Comment: @V.Gerasimenko Got the answer? I got the same issue

Comment: @Rakesh I dont resolve this issue. Now I use fastlane for ci and it works.