# App version shows as 0.0(0) after uploading to Fabric Beta

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I'm manually uploading the build in Crashlytics Beta. But the version number always shows as 0.0(0) like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181179/app-version-always-0-00-after-upload-to-fabric-beta) post. (Please don't mark as duplicate as this is a bit different as this occurs even with manual upload)  I'm using `Android Studio 3.1.3.` and `Gradle version 4.4`
Here's my gradle :

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'



compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Complete app/build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'http://kochava.bintray.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    flavorDimensions "default"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g" // Use gig increments depending on needs

    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debugConfig {

            storeFile file('keystore/debug.keystore')
            storePassword "/*password*/"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "/*password*/"
        }
        releaseConfig {

            storeFile file("keystore/release.keystore")
            storePassword "/*password*/"
            keyAlias "/*KeyAliasname*/"
            keyPassword "/*password*/"
        }
    }

//  Versioning
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    def versionBuild

    /*Setting default value for versionBuild which is the last incremented value stored in the file */
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        Properties versionProps = new Properties()
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger()
    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    /*Wrapping inside a method avoids auto incrementing on every gradle task run. Now it runs only when we build apk*/
    ext.autoIncrementBuildNumber = {

        if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
            def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
            versionProps.load(file("version.properties").newReader()/*new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile)*/)
            versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
            versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
            versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
        } else {
            throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
        }
    }

    def appId = "com.example.appName"
    def appName = "My App"
    def appBuildName = "appBuildName"
    def versionMajor = 6
    def versionMinor = 6
    def versionPatch = 0
    def appVersionName = "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    def appVersionCode = versionBuild

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId appId
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27

        resValue "bool", "is_prod", "false"
        resValue "bool", "is_prod_staging", "false"
        resValue "bool", "is_amazon", "false"

        // by default, enable logging
        resValue "bool", "is_debuggable", "true"

        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                def project = appBuildName
                def SEP = "-"
                def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name.toUpperCase()
                def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name.toUpperCase()
                def version = "v" + appVersionName + "." + (appVersionCode - 500000)

                def newApkName = project + SEP + version + SEP + buildType + SEP + flavor + ".apk"

                println "Output Apk Name: " + newApkName

                outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
            }
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
        uat {
            initWith(buildTypes.debug)
            applicationIdSuffix ".uat"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugConfig
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }
        staging {
            applicationIdSuffix ".uat"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugConfig
            debuggable false
            // we want the prod endpoint, with no logging
            resValue "bool", "is_prod_staging", "true"
            resValue "bool", "is_debuggable", "false"

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }
        prodStaging {
            initWith(buildTypes.staging)

            resValue "bool", "is_prod_staging", "false"
            resValue "bool", "is_prod", "true"
        }
        prodStagingNoSuffix {
            initWith(buildTypes.prodStaging)

            applicationIdSuffix ""

            debuggable false
        }
        release {
            // we want the prod endpoint, with no logging
            resValue "bool", "is_prod", "true"
            resValue "bool", "is_debuggable", "false"

            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true

        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        play {
            resValue "bool", "is_amazon", "false"
        }

        amazon {
            resValue "bool", "is_amazon", "true"
        }
    }

    // Hook to check if the release/debug task is among the tasks to be executed.
    //Let's make use of it
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
        def tasks = taskGraph.getAllTasks()
        tasks.find {
            println it
            if (it.name.toLowerCase().contains("package")
                    && !it.name.toLowerCase().contains("debug")
                    && !it.name.toLowerCase().contains("release")) {
                /* when run release task */
                /* note that the task cannot be a release as our release codes need to align */
                println("We've matches on the internal release task")
                autoIncrementBuildNumber()
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'com/kofax/android/abc/configuraPK'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    // Apache 2.0
    implementation files('libs/adobeMobileLibrary-4.13.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/dagger-2.7.jar')
    implementation files('libs/isg-3.2.0.0.0.761.jar')
    implementation files('libs/sdk-release.jar')
    implementation files('libs/login-with-amazon-sdk.jar')



    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    implementation 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.novoda:accessibilitools:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.kochava.base:tracker:3.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation project(path: ':linkedin-sdk', configuration: 'default')
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //rxjava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    //room
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1'
    //gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**Note : It used to work fine with Android Studio 2.2**

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Similar to the other post, what do you see in AndroidManifest.xml after the app has been compiled.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I don't see any sort of difference in the Manifest file.

Comment: You see 0.0 (0) in the Manifest of the built app?

Comment: Nope I dont see any 0.0 in manifest.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like something is changing the version post-build after the Fabric plugin is invoked.

Comment: I'm using 2.9.1 version of crashlytics. Should I try updating?

Comment: It may help, but I think something else is going on. Could you share your full build.gradle? Also, are you using our Gradle plugin to the submit the release, fastlane or the Fabric Android Studio plugin?

Comment: @MikeBonnell, I've updated the full build.gradle. Please take a look. I use Fabric Android Studio plugin and upload the apk manually.

Comment: Hi, any further updates on this? The same issue is happening to me and any help would be welcomed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Any idea on this?